# Is it possible for pllua to do the same thing as RETURN TABLE of plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pllua

example plpgsql RETURNS TABLE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aaa(
) RETURNS TABLE(
     value1 text
    ,value2 text
) AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT '1111'::text, '2222'::text;
   RETURN QUERY SELECT '3333'::text, '4444'::text;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is it possible for pllua to do the same thing as RETURN TABLE of plpgsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked to regress test and it is not possible. But plpgsq `RETURN QUERY` is "macro" for

```
FOR r IN SELECT ...
LOOP
  RETURN NEXT r;
END LOOP;
```

And it is possible in PLlua